# take action when all observables in a loop are resolved in Ionic 4 Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, promise, rxjs

I have a function called `getDevices()` which fetches an array of devices, iterate through each device and call `updateToServer()` method which updates those devices to the server. I need to fire another method after all `updateToServer` observables in loop are resolved how can I achieve that?

```
this.deviceService.getDevices().then((res : devicesInterface) => {
      if(res){        

        this.devices = res.devices;   

        this.devices.forEach(device => {  

          let data : ResUpdateDevices = {
            device: device,
            token: this.authenticationService.getToken(),
          };

          this.deviceService.updateDevicesToServer(data).subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res)  
          },err=>{
            console.log(err)
          });
        });

      } 
    })
```

I read in a forum about `Promise.all()` method but didn't find any working example on that.

Comment: What does updateDevicesToServer return? You talk about it as a promise, but promises don't have a `subscribe` method.

Comment: my bad, updateDevicesToServer returns Http call Observable, I need all http calls to get the response then fire another method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

> #### Why use forkJoin?
>
> This operator is best used when you have a group of observables and only care about the final emitted value of each. One common use case for this is if you wish to issue multiple requests on page load (or some other event) and only want to take action when a response has been received for all. In this way it is similar to how you might use `Promise.all`.
>
> Be aware that if any of the inner observables supplied to forkJoin error you will lose the value of any other observables that would or have already completed if you do not catch the error correctly on the inner observable. If you are only concerned with all inner observables completing successfully you can catch the error on the outside.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmnluu)

#### Your code

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.deviceService.getDevices().then((res : devicesInterface) => {
  if(res){        

    this.devices = res.devices;
    // use map instead of foreach to return a result
    var allObservables = this.devices.map(device => {  

        let data : ResUpdateDevices = {
            device: device,
            token: this.authenticationService.getToken(),
        };

        // return Observable
        return this.deviceService.updateDevicesToServer(data).pipe(tap(res => {
              console.log(res);  
          },err=>{
              console.log(err);
          }));
    });

    // call forkJoin on returned observables
    forkJoin(allObservables).subscribe(() => /* do something here */);
  } 
})
```

Comment: I console.log("All Promise Resolved") in do something hear resulting in runtime error 
ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: @RishabhGusain - sorry, that should have been `pipe` with `tap` to get the result but not subscribe within the loop. I fixed the code but also supplied a https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmnluu with a very basic example of how it works.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you are trying to achieve, Observables would be really helpful. Something like that should work (did not test it) :

```
    // make getDevices() to return an observable, or if you can't use 'from' to create a new Observable from a promise
    this.deviceService.getDevices()
        .pipe(
          flatMap(d => d), // each items from array emitted one by one
          map(device => {  
            let data : ResUpdateDevices = {
              device: device,
              token: this.authenticationService.getToken(),
            };
            return this.deviceService.updateDevicesToServer(data);
          }),
          tap(res => /*do something else without updating value emitted by Observable*/)
        ).subscribe(res => {
          // do something
          console.log(res);
        }, err=>{
          console.log(err)
        });
```